How do I give a user permission to run the Apps Script in a Google Sheet?
I have created a pair of Apps Sheet files which run fine for me. I have shared the Google Sheets with other users. But those users cannot execute the scripts. How do I give them permission?
I thought when the user first tried to execute the script, he or she could ask for permission, and I would get a notification and could respond. But the user is stuck at a screen asking to confirm the google account or to switch accounts, but there is no way out of the dialog.

How do I ask a good question?

To access the page and request access to a Google Sheets spreadsheet or other file hosted on Google Drive, the user should sign in to their Google account first. You might have to train the intended users for your spreadsheet / script about how to do this or refer them to the Google Accounts Help Center ‑> https://support.google.com/accounts, more specifically Create a Google Account.
